# Words in lines in text in string in list. How to return a neccessary output?

Tags: string, list, python-3.x, text

stackoverfollowers!
i have a task that i can't combat till the end

> To write a function `words(a, b, txt)`
>
> `txt = ['All in the golden afternoon\nFull leisurely we glide;\nFor
>   both our oars, with little skill,\nBy little arms are plied,\nWhile
>   little hands make vain pretence\nOur wanderings to guide.']`
>
> `a = 6`
>
> `b = 8`
>
> A function should return all the words with length from 6 to 8 letters
>   of each line. If a line don't have words like this, it returns empty
>   string. If a line have more than one word they should have an order
>   like they have in a line
>
> Function `words(a,b,txt)` should return
>
> `['golden', '', 'little','little', 'little pretence', '']`

i have wrote a code like this:

```
def noalpha(s):   


    noa = ''         # choose all non-alphabetic symbols
    for c in s:
        if not (c in noa or c.isalpha()):
            noa += c
    return noa

def words(a,b,txt):

    lst = []
    for i in txt:       # work with a whole text that is one element in list txt

        i = i.splitlines()    # split text in lines \n
        for s in i:           # iteration in lines
            s = s.split()
            for w in s:       # iteration in words
                w = w.replace(noalpha(w), '')

                if a <= len(w) <= b:
                    lst.append(w)


        return lst
```

so i can't find the way to:

1. return `''` (an empty string) for a whole line that doesn't contain words of necessary length
2. if a line contains more that one word i can't return them like `'word1 word2 word3'`

Comment: Did you correctly indent your final `return`? Is the output correct, how can you return `'little pretence'` when you split on words? You can `return ' '.join(lst)` to return the words as a string.

Comment: BTW: What issue are you having because it seems to return the expected output.

Comment: my function return list like this ['golden', 'little', 'little', 'little', 'pretence'] but it should return like this ['golden', '', 'little', 'little', 'little pretence', '']
so i don't have a vote strings and words 'little' and 'pretence'  are returning separately while it is needed to return them in one string as they belong to the same line

Comment: this is it! i'd like to return a string of words that belongs to the same line not each word separately, but i don't know how to correct my code!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
def alpha(word):
    return ''.join(char for char in word if char.isalpha())


result = []
for line in txt[0].splitlines():
    words = [alpha(word) for word in line.split()]
    result.append(' '.join(word for word in words if a <= len(word) <= b))
```